# Двоеточие или тире в БСП?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в данном предложении:

> Тема домашнего задания "Роль личности в истории" на основе семи или восьми предлагаемых источников.

Answer (score 1):

Я написал бы так: Тема домашнего задания - "Роль личности в истории" (на основе семи или восьми предлагаемых источников).

Comment: Скобки - хорошо, а если без скобок?

Comment: В крайнем случае вместо скобки - тире, но звучать и выглядеть это будет коряво.